# Embed purchase funnel from a website in Ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, inappbrowser

I am improving my Ionic app, so the users can now buy the products.

But those are the same product that are also present on the corresponding website, and I would like to embed the "purchase funnel" or "payment gateway" from this website into my Ionic app. Mostly because the funnel is complicated because the products are "custom" with a lot of attributes.

Is that possible with the `inappbrowser` ionic plugin? Will the payment be safe enough (https)? Will a third-party payment be possible, for example via PayPal?

Answer (score 2):

`InAppBrowser` window behaves like a standard web browser, it  will use the native browser's security features and can’t access `Cordova APIs`. So it mainly depends on whether the the website can be trusted on any browser. Even otherwise `native` functionalities can't be exploited.

Other than that , payment gateways should work as it works on a website . In case you want some scripts to be injected into the website , you can check out [executeScript](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserexecutescript) in `inAppBrowser`.

**edit**

Something which can be noted is that the version of `WebKit` you have available depends on your device  and isn't necessarily the same as the default browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this github repository. I think it will help you for sure: https://github.com/IonicU/payuhybridappintegration
Also, there are very good examples given by the PayPal Developers: https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/